# Solving equation with two variables for bounded intervals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do I approach solving problems like for example finding $x,y$ with $0\leq x \leq 3$ and $4\leq y\leq 6$ for
$$
\frac{x-1}{4}=\frac{y-1}{5}
$$

I know that the solution is $(29/9, 34/9)$ but how do I get to that solution generally?

Comment: $34/9<4$, so that's not a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

$\dfrac{y-1}5=\dfrac{x-1}4\iff y-1=\dfrac54x-\dfrac54\iff y=\dfrac54x-\dfrac14$

and

$0\le x\le3\iff0\le\dfrac54x\le\dfrac{15}4\iff-\dfrac14\le\dfrac54x-\dfrac14\le\dfrac{14}4$

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit more, where do I go from here? :)

Comment: I have shown if $\dfrac{y-1}5=\dfrac{x-1}4$ and $0\le x\le 3$, then $-\dfrac14\le y\le\dfrac{14}4$, so not $4\le y\le 6$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac a b = \frac c d \implies ad=bc$$.

**Proof**. Let $\frac a b = k$ for some $k\not=0$. Then $a=bk$. Also that $\frac c d = \frac a b = k$. Therefore $c=dk$. Therefore $a(dk) = (bk)c$. Therefore $ad=bc$.

Now if $k=0$, then $a=c=0$. Therefore $ad=bc=0$. $\square$

Comment: well to be honest I don't understand what this means... this proof is of course trivial. how is that related to the problem?

Comment: @AnTheBan so 5x-5=4y-4. So 5x-1=4y. So y=(5x-1)/4 Since 0 < x < 3, -1/4 < y <7/2. Since y>4, no solution.